# Finding duplicate values in a data frame inside a python Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to find the duplicate values inside a certain column found inside a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the file names and the values are the column headers (ID, and Group). I want to read all the IDs and see if there are any duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

folderpath= (r"path")

filenames = dict()
for file in os.listdir(folderpath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        filenames[file] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join((folderpath), file))

splitfiles=({k:v for k,v in filenames.items() if 'split.csv' in k})
```

I am reading csv files from a folder and store the filename as the dictionary key and the values are the column headings with the dictionary data type as Data frame. I only want to keep all the file names that contain "split_csv" so that's the splitfiles variable.

splitfiles dictionary looks something like this:

```
splitfiles=
{{test1_split: {'ID': 123, 'Group': 'whatever'},
{test2_split: {'ID': 123, 'Group': 'whatever'}}
```

I want to be able to find when there are duplicate ID between the files I have tried something like this but it only work for tuples in a dictionary not a dataframe:

```
rev_dict = {}
for key, value in splitfiles.items():
    rev_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
result = [key for key, values in rev_dict.items()
                              if len(values) > 1]

print("duplicate values", str(result))
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'

My desired output is something like "duplicate values [2]"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dictionary you're trying to get the duplicates from is like the example you provided, this will get you the number of duplicates:

```
data_list = []
for value in splitfiles.values():
  data_list.append(value["ID"])
data_set = set(data_list)
print("Duplicate values: ",len(data_list)-len(data_set))
```

Comment: I update what the dictionary might look like. the basic layout is file name as the key, column heading as the first value and then the data for the heading as a 2nd value, might be more of a nested dictionary. its a dictionary with a pd data frame as its type.

Comment: I updated it to what should work with the current description of the data.

Comment: it gives an unhasbale type series error